# in what language is bashrc written

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

I came across a [cool way](https://superuser.com/questions/449687/using-cd-to-go-up-multiple-directory-levels/449705) to go up more than 1 directory level by adding a function to the .bashrc file.

It is done by just opening the .bashrc file and inserting the function:

```
#user defined functions
function cd_up() {
  cd $(printf "%0.s../" $(seq 1 $1 ));
}
alias 'cd..'='cd_up'
```

I want to understand how to read it.

What language is it written in?

Comment: In Bash........

Comment: I believe you already mentioned the answer to that in your own post (three times if we take into account the tag used on your post) :D

Comment: The commandline you are using is called "bash".  More than just a way to execute single commands it is actually a programming language in it's own right (based on "shell").  The manual for it is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)

Comment: Note that the function does not actually need to be added to the `.bashrc` file. Instead, you could paste its definition into a terminal where `bash` is already running. This shows that the function definition is written in the same language that you use to interact with the shell at the shell's prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contents of `.bashrc` are executed by Bash itself, in the same way it executes scripts, or indeed what ever an interactive shell is fed. It's a variant of the POSIX shell language, with a number of extensions (some borrowed from other shells, mainly Ksh, some created by Bash itself).

Here, `function cd_up() { ... ; }` defines a function. The standard form for this would be just `cd_up() { ... ; }`, without the `function` keyword. The `$(...)` is a command substitution, it runs the command inside, and places its output as command line arguments.

The `printf "%0.s../"` is the trick here. `printf` takes a format string, similar to the C function `printf()`, and a number of arguments to print using that format string. Importantly, it also repeats the format string as many times as necessary to use all arguments (which the C function doesn't and can't do). The specifier `%0.s` tells to print the argument as a string with zero width, so in effect, the arguments are *not* printed.

But the constant part `../` *is* printed once for each argument, meaning that `printf "%0.s../" a b` would print it twice, etc. `$(seq 1 $1)` is another command substitution, and since `seq` prints a list of numbers, it is used to provide the required amount of arguments to `printf`. `$1` is the first argument to the current function `cd_up`.

So, e.g. `cd_up 2`, would first run `seq 1 2`, which prints `1 2`. This is passed as an argument to `printf`, so you get `printf "%0.s../" 1 2` which prints `../../`. This is passed to `cd`, and `cd ../../` is run, going up two levels in the directory tree.

With `set -x`, you can see the commands the shell actually runs. Bash even indicates the nesting level with the `+` signs:

```
/tmp/foo$ set -x
/tmp/foo$ cd_up 2
+ cd_up 2
+++ seq 1 2
++ printf %0.s../ 1 2
+ cd ../../
/$
```

Note that it doesn't really matter *what* the output of `seq` is, just that there's the correct number of words in it. Since the command substitutions are not quoted, the output goes through [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), meaning that it's split on whitespace to multiple arguments. `printf "%0.s../" "$(seq 1 $1)"` would always pass just one argument after the format string. (See the examples on the linked page.)

---

Another way to write a similar function, with less tricks would be a simple loop. Almost in POSIX sh (`local` isn't POSIX):

```
cd_up() {
   local i=$1 
   while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; do 
      cd ..
      i=$((i - 1))
   done
}
```

or in Bash/Zsh, using the arithmetic for loop:

```
cd_up() { 
    local i
    for (( i=$1; i > 0; i-- )); do 
        cd ..
    done
}
```

Though the version with `printf` is better in that it runs `cd` only once, so `cd -` returns back to the original directory, not an in-between one. (Fixing that is left as an exercise.)

For resource on the shell language, see e.g.

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide, and
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/bash/info

Answer (score 2):

bashrc is a bash script that runs whenever bash is started interactively.